# How can I find the local maximum of $f(x,y)=x^2ye^{-x^2-2y^2} $ without using second partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can I find the local and global maximum of $f(x,y)=x^2ye^{-x^2-2y^2}  $ without using the second partial derivative?
There is a proof in the book that finds it that I have trouble understanding.
Can someone make things clearer?
It goes like this:

$\lim \limits_{x +y^2\to\infty}f(x,y)=0\ $, therefore exists such $R\ge10$ for which $f(x,y)\le\frac{1}{100}$ for $x^2+y^2\ge R^2$.
The biggest value of $f(x,y)$ in the circle $x^2+y^2\le R^2$ is in $f(-1;\frac{1}{2})=f(1;\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt e^3}$ therefore there is local and global maximum in $f(-1;\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(1;\frac{1}{2})$.

Where does $R\ge10$ come from? It seems like an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ where $g(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$ and $h(y)=ye^{-2y^2}$

Now suppose $y \gt 0$. Find the local/global maximum of $g$, let's say at $x_{max}$ and local/global maximum of $h$, let's say at $y_{max}$. Then $(x_{max},y_{max})$ is a local/global maximum for $f(x,y)$.

Then treat the case $y \le 0$ in a  similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the sign of the first partial derivatives.

If it goes from positive to negative when either of the variables are increasing, then you have fond the local maximum.

---

$\displaystyle\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xye^{-x^2-2y^2}-2x^3ye^{-x^2-2y^2}$

$\displaystyle\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^2e^{-x^2-2y^2}-4x^2y^2e^{-x^2-2y^2}$

---

$\displaystyle\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ has the same sign as $y$ when $x<-1$ or $0<x<1$, and opposite sign when $-1<x<0$ or $1<x$, and zero when $x=-1,0,1$.

Comment: see my edit i made a typo in the power

Comment: The limit at any infinity is zero due to $e^{-x^2 -2y^2}$